# SQL Server 2008R2 problem: "Property Size is not available for Database []..."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

when i try to view properties of my database, i get this error:

Property Size is not available for database [database name] this property may not exists for this object or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights (Microsoft.smo..)

Is there any way to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my database was physically corrupted, becouse of hardware issues :(.
Thanks for all for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this kind of error is encountered when you are not the database owner. I'm not that sure though but, this might be worth a try. Check on the database owner, and try to change it to the current logged-in user.

By the way, is this a production database? You need to do a simulation on a test database to make sure, I strongly recommend not to do trial and error stuff on the production server. :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue can occur if the drive runs out of space. Resolve the space issue then run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE against the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and was little freaked out. I ran

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(database_name)
```

against the database and it fixed the issue, but I see where others have had to reset the database owner in order to fix this problem. You can see the database owners by running

```
sp_helpdb
```

You can change the owner by running

```
sp_changedbowner [ @loginame = ] ‘login’
                         [ , [ @map= ] remap_alias_flag ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index rebuild running, it may prevent you from checking the property. I suggest trying again later. If it never worked, make sure you have enough permissions.